# Flutter / Dart components visual scheme?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

This might be a bit out of the box question, but not being much of an abstract thinker, I find dart syntax unreasonably confusing. Apparently, for example, *ThemeData* is a *widget* that is also a *class* that has a *class* *dark()* that has a *property* that is actually a *constructo*r, that has a *class*... Pure nonsense.

Does anyone has a link to a nice, clear, schematic, visual explanation of how the components are actually called, how are they connected together etc, so that the person that has more of a visual perception can understand what's going on?

I did some coding in the past, but I'm having hard times getting my head around flutter / dart syntax, as if entire google sat together and said "how we can make it look as confusing as possible? Maybe we can make *Color* and *Colors* two different classes? Great! More ideas like that anyone?!"

Any leads to a common sense, not written-by-developer explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Widget` is a `class`. So every extension of `Widget` is also a `class`.

Each class can have one constructor. There can be "named constructions", so-called `factories` which are predefined constructors, like `ThemeData`'s `dark()`.

Finally `Color` is a class that describes a single color. `Colors` is a class that holds a lot of constants for you to use.

It is not that difficult at the end of the day, but you cannot expect to learn it all at once.